# I'm trying to run an Ipython notebook, except it's giving me an "astype timedelta64" error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython, gis

I'm interested in big data, and I recently happened upon this Ipython notebook: https://github.com/lmart999/GIS/blob/master/SF_GIS_Crime.ipynb

And immediately downloaded it and attempted to run it. The first dozen or so cells ran normally, even the matplotlib charts.

Until I got to these lines:

```
#  Lets use real dates for plotting
days_from_start=pd.Series(t_all.index*30).astype('timedelta64[D]')
dates_for_plot=date.min()+days_from_start
time_labels=dates_for_plot.map(lambda x: str(x.year)+'-'+str(x.month))
```

Which gave a very long error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-4a793ff06024> in <module>()
      1 # Lets use real dates for plotting
----> 2 days_from_start=pd.Series(t_all.index*30).astype('timedelta64[D]')
      3 dates_for_plot=date.min()+days_from_start
      4 time_labels=dates_for_plot.map(lambda x: str(x.year)+'-'+str(x.month))
```

*[---50 lines of error messages---]*

```
lib.pyx in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:12697)()

util.pxd in util.set_value_at (pandas/lib.c:49357)()

ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

If you need me to post the entire message I will, but I think the core problem may have something to to with a conflict between the versions of numpy and pandas.

Can someone with more experience show me how I should change this? I'm running Ubntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Numpy no longer supports creating `timedelta64` objects from a float (presumably that was possible when the notebook was published).

You need to first cast the scaled-up index into integers before casting to `timedelta64`.

```
days_from_start=pd.Series(t_all.index*30).astype('int').astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Comment: Got it, trying this now.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed that problem. Thanks, a lot.